# My Title doesn't want to be overlayed on top of the image inside of the div, instead it places the text in the div below

Tags: html, css

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDNPP.png)

So I have a grid with several div elements. I want my text to be inside of the div ".item2", but as you can see in the image it instead puts the text down below the div itself, and instead in the div below. I have no idea why it does this, and so I was wondering, how can I place my text on top of the image, inside of the div?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Kiona Regular;
    src: url('Kiona-Regular.ttf');
} 

@font-face {
    font-family: Lane;
    src: url('LANENAR_.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Title;
    src: url("BebasNeue-Regular.ttf");
}

.item1 {
    grid-area: header;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Kiona Regular;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor:default;
    z-index: 2;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

.title-text {
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px white;
    transition-property: text-shadow;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.title-text:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 11px white, 0 0 11px white;
}

.item2 {
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: 0;
    height: 30vh;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
      pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}
.item3 {
    grid-area: footer;
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    line-height: 30%;
    opacity: 0.68;
}

.item4 {
    grid-area: main2;
    background-color: 0;
    height: 55vh;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header'
    'main main main main main'
    'main2 main2 main2 main2 main2'
    'footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

table, th {
    background-color: black;
    height: 8vh;
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}

.has-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.has-dropdown:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown {
    width: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -58px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    border: 0px solid white;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #222222;
    font-family: Lane;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-indent: 4px;
}
.dropdown a {
    color: white;
}
.dropdown div:hover {
    background-color: #444444;
}

#BackgroundVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.logo {
  width:20%;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  margin:auto;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

.ctext {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Title;
    font-size: 48px;
    veritcal-align: left;
    color: white;
    z-index: 4;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.largeimg {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
-webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
-moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
-ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pragerio</title>
<link href="Fera1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="TheBigProject2.js" type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
<img class="logo" src="Pragerio Logo.svg" height="211px" id="PragerioLogo" alt="Pragerio Logo">
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
     <table readonly>
    <tr>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">FERA</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>About</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Compare</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">SENSAÇÃO</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>About</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Compare</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">PRESS</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>News</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Visits</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">ABOUT</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>Heritage</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Contact</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
  </tr>
      </table>
         </div>
    <div class="item2">
        <img class="largeimg" src="HiResPhoto181.png" alt="Image">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item4"></div>
  <div class="item3">
    <span class="ctext">Attention</span><br>
    <span class="ctext">2021 © Pragerio, Ltda. and Partners</span><br>
    <span class="ctext">(Erik Granlund)</span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to position a div inside another div, you can use a very simple technic. First, you should give `position: relative;` property to your the parent (wrapper) div. Then, give `position: absolute;` to the child div and to locate it as you want with `top: X`, `right: X`, `bottom: X`, `left: X` properties.

```css
  @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Kiona Regular;
    src: url('Kiona-Regular.ttf');
} 

@font-face {
    font-family: Lane;
    src: url('LANENAR_.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Title;
    src: url("BebasNeue-Regular.ttf");
}

.item1 {
    grid-area: header;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Kiona Regular;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor:default;
    z-index: 2;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

.title-text {
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px white;
    transition-property: text-shadow;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.title-text:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 11px white, 0 0 11px white;
}

.item2 {
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: 0;
    height: 30vh;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
      pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}
.item3 {
    grid-area: footer;
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    line-height: 30%;
    opacity: 0.68;
}

.item4 {
    grid-area: main2;
    background-color: 0;
    height: 55vh;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header'
    'main main main main main'
    'main2 main2 main2 main2 main2'
    'footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

table, th {
    background-color: black;
    height: 8vh;
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}

.has-dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.has-dropdown:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown {
    width: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -58px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    border: 0px solid white;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #222222;
    font-family: Lane;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-indent: 4px;
}
.dropdown a {
    color: white;
}
.dropdown div:hover {
    background-color: #444444;
}

#BackgroundVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.logo {
  width:20%;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  margin:auto;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

.ctext {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Title;
    font-size: 48px;
    veritcal-align: left;
    color: white;
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.largeimg {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
-webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
-moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
-ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pragerio</title>
<link href="Fera1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="TheBigProject2.js" type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
<img class="logo" src="Pragerio Logo.svg" height="211px" id="PragerioLogo" alt="Pragerio Logo">
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
     <table readonly>
    <tr>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">FERA</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>About</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Compare</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">SENSAÇÃO</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>About</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Compare</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">PRESS</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>News</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Visits</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
    <th class="has-dropdown">
        <span class="title-text">ABOUT</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><div>Heritage</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div>Contact</div></a>
        </div>
        </th>
  </tr>
      </table>
         </div>
    <div class="item2">
        <img class="largeimg" src="HiResPhoto181.png" alt="Image">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item4"></div>
  <div class="item3">
    <span class="ctext">Attention</span><br>
    <span class="ctext">2021 © Pragerio, Ltda. and Partners</span><br>
    <span class="ctext">(Erik Granlund)</span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Item2 is a div which contains the img and the text. The browser parses the HTML and first paints the image and below that the title.

If you want the title inside the picture you can give the Item2 div a background image in CSS (and remove the image in the HTML)

```
.item2 {
    background-image: url("HiResPhoto181.png");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: 0;
    height: 30vh;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
      pointer-events: none;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}




 <div class="item2">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, I didn't really want to place a div inside a div, I just wanted the text to be inside of my div. The problem was that it isn't, for some reason, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the image and the text into a container by using the following HTML div tag.

```
<div class="container item2"> <!-- Here you are using both the 'Container' class and your 'item2' class for a single element --> 

</div>
```

Then you can use the following CSS for your 'container' class to vertically and horizontally align the text so it is positioned in the centre of the image.

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```